# EF Core conditional relationship without foreign key

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have a table that has generic ObjectType (string) and ObjectId (int) columns that correspond to other tables and their primary keys respectively. What is the best way to set up these condition relationships with EF Core? (One to many relationship). Note: Normally I would just create properties on the C# data models that query the database for these conditions, but my data models are just POCOs, they have no access to the database.

SQL Server

```
Table Communication {
    Id int,
    ObjectType string,
    ObjectId int
}

Table Cat {
    Id int,
    ...
}

Table Dog {
    Id int,
    ...
}
```

C# Models

```
class Communication {
    int Id
    string objectType
    int objectId
    Cat cat -> populated if objectType = "Cat"
    Dog dog -> populated if objectType = "Dog"
}

class Cat {
    int Id,
    ...
    List<Communication> communications -> all associated Communications
}

class Dog {
    int Id,
    ...
    List<Communication> communications -> all associated Communications
}
```

Example Communication database records

```
Id    ObjectType    ObjectId
1     Cat           55
2     Cat           78
3     Dog           13
```

Comment: do you mean that you have a table which holds constraints between tables? and you want to use this table to dynamically create relationships in your DbContext?

Comment: @Simonare there aren't any database contraints setup if that's what you mean. The only database "relationship" between the Communications table and everything else is the ObjectType and ObjectId fields which correspond to the table names and primary key value respectively.

Comment: yes, I was asking that actually. I have something in my mind but I need to think about it first. thank you for clarification

Comment: @Simonare I edited the post with some more clarifications if it helps

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot generate strongly-typed classes on runtime. you may consider to have seperate console application which generates you these classes. DbContext can be generated by using ObjectType and ObjectId tables but strongly typed classes would be problem. Can you consider this and make comment on it?

Comment: @Simonare I'm probably misunderstanding something, but I'm not trying to generate strongly typed classes on runtime, the classes (Cat and Dog) are already generated and exist. I just want the relationships to be made with those tables/classes to the Communcations table/class based on the values in the Communication.ObjectType and Communication.ObjectId fields.

Comment: Check [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), maybe helps

Comment: This sounds like yet another request for polymorphic associations. So no, EF (Core) currently supports only FK associations.